# Ask to remove Tag Synonym [php-errors] to [php]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

The [php-errors](/questions/tagged/php-errors) has been recently added [as synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms/) to [php](/questions/tagged/php).

It was working pretty well in the past to find related content when you tagged some component (e.g. like [phpunit](/questions/tagged/phpunit) or [simplexml](/questions/tagged/simplexml)) with it.

This benefit is now gone. Most often with errors related if not duplicate questions are easily spotted so it would be of great help to not have it as synonym.

This is (was) an important tool used to direct duplicates and reference questions over time, tagging is more distinct that plain text search and allows meta-categorization (seems to be it's necessary to add this here on this website, in case anyone wonders I state the obvious).

Comment: I am in favor. @hakre here is the #1 duplicate finder in all of [se]. He knows what he's talking about when it comes to search.

Comment: @hakre I get that you can't tag with [tag:php-errors] and search for it, but _why_ do you need to be able to tag with it and search for it? Why do we need an errors tag for PHP specifically? Is it for discussing PHP errors as opposed to PHP exceptions? At first I thought it was just for discussing general programming errors in a PHP context, which doesn't seem like a good tag to have.

Comment: [This is the first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289754/getting-blank-page-on-a-joomla-site) that comes up with the [tag:php-errors] tag. I don't see how it's beneficial on that question over just a plain [tag:php] tag.

Comment: @animuson: Because a whole lot of questions on PHP are about errors, so searching for errors to duplicate against seems logical.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha How would the [tag:php-errors] tag help in that? Labeling every single error in PHP as a "PHP error" doesn't make them more searchable. Like Jonathan said, `[php] error` will yield the same results.

Comment: @hakre "for exceptions what you say even sounds a bit constructed (nade-up) to me": I'm talking about how PHP has [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) and it has [exceptions](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), which are different things handled separately. I am not making things up or (as you just mentioned) making assumptions, I'm asking you to say why you'd need to use this tag because it sounds like _not a good kind of tag_. If it's a good tag, I'm trying to understand from you _why_. I agree I don't need it since my PHP days are years ago.

Comment: The way I see it, a [tag:php-errors] tag is like throwing out a 500 Internal Server Error. It could mean just about anything, and doesn't help categorize a problem whatsoever. You claim it would help searching, but it would still be just as much like finding a needle in a haystack. You need more descriptive search terms than "error" to find anything useful.

Comment: @animuson: That tag plus another, I wonder how that is unclear through the question and I hope this is now more clear to you. Also a PHP error can result in a HTTP status code 500, but that one has it's own tag. Just saying, but you can also synonymize it because every tag is useless as you can search for the text instead (just joking a bit about the hilarious argumentation that search works better with text than with dedicated tags) :)

Comment: And in any case, I can create a new tag, but then the value of the ca. 800 so tagged tags would be gone. It round about took a year or so.